# repeat my slide show

Tags: ios, sdk

i tried to make this slideshow repeat for infinity and didn't work.please help me

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
}


-(void)changeImage

{
    [UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"];
} completion:^(BOOL done){
    [UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    } completion:^(BOOL done){
        [UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
        } completion:^(BOOL done){
        }];
    }];
}];
}
```

Comment: You're definitely making this over complicated. Have a look at `Viruss mca`s answer.

Comment: its not that complicated !!

Answer (score 4):

Rather than Doing this You can use inbuilt property of UIImageview for animation images.

You can try Something Like,

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
nil];

imageView.animationImages = images;
imageView.animationDuration = 1;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = nonStop repeat
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: this is normal animation i need custom animation so images fading when change from one to another.need to apply one like this UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom

Comment: can you add some effects to this animation

Answer (score 1):

You can get this from example : http://goo.gl/8Gj6m0

Comment: i have done this before.i need more options for transition of images when changes like this one UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom